# What language is "Solutio problematis ad geometriam situs pertinentis" written in?

Tags: language

The article by Euler titled "Solutio problematis ad geometriam situs pertinentis"(The Seven Bridges of Königsberg) is considered as the first work in both *Topology* and *Graph Theory*. However, in the original paper, I am not quite sure what language it was written in. I asked AI, and it told me it's in Latin. I'm a bit unsure because I'm writing a comprehensive article and need to ensure accuracy.

The language doesn't seem to be very common today, and I feel that English shares many similarities with it.

Comment: For future reference, e.g. Google Translate's "Detect language" function can be quite useful in these situations. It correctly identifies the title as written in Latin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in Latin. The title is pretty clearly Latin (even with just a little familiarity with Latin, that is clear) but you can also look [here](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/53/) which says it was written in Latin. Also, Latin was the language that European people wrote in back then. (Euler also wrote some papers in German, but this clearly isn't German) and he wrote letters in Russian, but probably did not produce any papers in Russian (some were written in German and translated).  In any case, this clearly isn't Russian.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. By the way, its English translation version can be seen in the book " Biggs, N.; Lloyd, E.; Wilson, R. (1986), Graph Theory, 1736-1936, Oxford University Press"

Comment: "Latin was the language people wrote in back then" Well, I get your meaning, but this is true only for certain parts of the world.

Comment: Good point, @Snijderfrey. I will amend my answer.